# Changing default text via css not working

Tags: html, css

I have a page with the following set as default:

```
<h1 class="header">
   <span class="icon icon-lock"></span>
   "Checkout"
</h1>
```

in my cshtml page I test for a certain condition and if it's met I add another class onto the  element called "checkout2" and I can see this in chrome tools. so the html becomes:

```
<h1 class="header checkout2">
       <span class="icon icon-lock"></span>
       "Checkout"
    </h1>
```

So now in my css I have the following:

```
.checkout2:after {
   content: 'My new text';
}
```

the content doesn't change any ideas why?

Comment: Where is your `checkout2` class in the HTML? I mean. I know you apply it later, but it's working just adding on HTML now. You should provide all of it (the code adding the class) for testing.

Comment: maybe content: 'My new text' !important; will do the work but still not getting clear idea

Comment: I see 'My new text' being added to the end of that "Checkout" text, not replacing it.  But that is what I would expect.  If you don't see it at all, maybe you are limiting the width of the header so that additional text ends up hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like just poor semantics since there is no .checkout2 in your example I'm going to assume you're using `addClass` to add it perhaps to the wrong element. Here's an example of how it would work... Cheers

```css
.header:after {
  content: attr(data-first);
}

.header:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-second);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header" data-first="Hover Me!" data-second="WEEEEEEEEEEE!">
   <span class="icon icon-lock"></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: I want the text to be replaced

Comment: @bilpor edited, keep in mind the `content` attribute **only** applies to pseudo elements. So if you want to replace innerHTML you have to use javascript.